# xpath help -- preceding and following paragraph

Tags: xpath

I'm starting with just the xml:id of a given paragraph and I'm trying to get the xml:id of the preceding paragraph. Here's what I have so far. Right now, I'm getting all the xml:id's of the preceding paragraphs. But I only want the immediately preceding paragraph.

```
//p[following::p[@xml:id='d1l46adaacp']]/@xml:id
```

Please help.

Comment: Post the sample XML data

Comment: //p[@xml:id='d1l46adaacp']/preceding::p[1]/@xml:id - i think this works -- someone post this and get free points. I was thinking about things a little bit backward.

Comment: You know you can answer your question

Answer (score 2):

Here's the answer I discovered after my post.

Basically I was thinking about things backward. I was looking for any `p` that had a following `p` with the designated `xml:id`. I was not able to add [1] to the end because this was giving me any `p` that was first in its parent element.

What I have below works better. Now instead of trying to go straight to the preceding paragraph, I start at the paragraph whose `xml:id` I know, then I go to the preceding paragraph, stop at the first one [1], and ask for the xml:id.

```
//p[@xml:id='d1l46adaacp']/preceding::p[1]/@xml:id
```